# Magento : Add data to quote item object in an observer

Tags: magento, object, events

This is what I want to do:

1. When I add a product to the cart, I catch the event
2. In the associated observer, I want to add a data to the current quote item and save it.
3. In the shopping cart, I get back this information in order to display it

This is what I do in the observer :

```
 $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
 $item->setData('results',$results);
```

In the cart I’m trying to log this value like that :

```
 Mage::log($_item->getData('results'));
```

But this value is empty. I think the “results” attribute is not persistent.

Can you help me to solve my problem ?

Please let me know if some more details are required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I come to you with a solution !
I found the “ sales_flat_quote_item_option” table and I stock my value in it.

```
if(isset($results))
{
        $item->addOption(array(
              "product_id" => $item->getProduct()->getId(),
              "product" => $item->getProduct(),
              "code" => "results",
              "value" => serialize($results)
        ));
        $item->save();
}
```

And I get this value in the cart like that.

```
$results_data = $_item->getOptionByCode("results");
if(!is_null($results_data))
     $results = unserialize($results_data->getValue());
```

It’s working like a charm, thank you for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
 $item->setData('results',$results);
```

Where have you initialized $results.
As there appears to be no value associated with $results hence you getting a blank value.

Comment: It's a section of my code : $results is not empty, I tested it with a Mage::log in the observer.